# Arithmetic overflow on column sum in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get a column total but when i run this query i get the following error. Any advice?

```
SELECT SUM(Size) as total
FROM  AllDocs
Where DirName LIKE 'sites/test/test%'


ERROR:
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Comment: Looks like the sum of all those sizes is bigger than MAX int....

Answer (score 56, accepted):

While all your sizes can fit into `INT` (up to `2^31 - 1`), their `SUM` cannot.

Cast them into `BIGINT`:

```
SELECT  SUM(CAST(Size AS BIGINT)) as total
FROM    AllDocs
WHERE   DirName LIKE 'sites/test/test%'
```