# SQL Teradata evaluation order of case when then else

Tags: sql, teradata, operator-precedence, case-when

I want to run this query on the official Teradata Express for VMware Player (TDE 15.00.01 SLES 10 for VMware (40GB) with Viewpoint):

```
SELECT 'MaxValue' column_name,
       COUNT("MaxValue") AS count_value,
       COUNT(DISTINCT("MaxValue")) AS count_dist_value,
       MIN("MaxValue") AS min_value,
       MAX("MaxValue") AS max_value,
       CASE WHEN max_value > 99999999999999 THEN 99999999999999
            ELSE SUM("MaxValue") END AS sum_value
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM "DBC"."IdCol") AS xy;
```

But I get this error:

> Executed as Single statement.  Failed [2616 : 22003] Numeric overflow
>   occurred during computation.   Elapsed time = 00:00:00.115
>
> STATEMENT 1: Select Statement failed.

So my question is that why the ELSE statement is evaluated when the CASE logic is True? And how can I run this query? I want the COUNT, MIN, MAX, AVG, SUM etc. informations from unknown tables where I don't know if a column contains 20 digit long numbers or not.
Thank you!

Comment: Don't know much about teradata, but maybe you just need to cast whatever value you are passing to SUM,MIN,MAX... into a wider datatype (INT => BIGINT?) to make it not overflow. (like you would do in SQL Server for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1222890/2186023)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [DrCopyPaste](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2186023/drcopypaste)'s comment, the solution is:

```
SELECT 'MaxValue' column_name,
       COUNT("MaxValue") AS count_value,
       COUNT(DISTINCT("MaxValue")) AS count_dist_value,
       MIN("MaxValue") AS min_value,
       MAX("MaxValue") AS max_value,
       CASE WHEN max_value > 99999999999999 THEN 99999999999999
            ELSE SUM(CAST("MaxValue" AS BIGINT)) END AS sum_value
FROM (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM "DBC"."IdCol") AS xy;
```

Thank you!